# Implementing hashCode for a BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, equals

In Java to compare two objections for equality, you must implement both the `equals` method and the `hashCode` method. I need to compare two BSTs for equality. How do I implement the `hashCode` method in such a case? Now, implementing the `hashCode` on the `Node` class is simple enough: imagine my data is `int`. But I cannot just add the values of the node to check if the trees are equal. So how do I do it? Has anyone done this successfully?

I am thinking of many different things that I can do, but I am not sure how scalable they would be. For example I could use level order and for each level multiply by a large prime number, but I can't be sure that this would work. So maybe someone who understands better can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to check that the _structure_ of the trees are the same, or just the contents?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I never actually thought of that. Thanks. I am guessing both. So yes, both: Structure and content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I cannot just add the values of the node to check if the trees are equal.

Sure you can.  `hashCode`s do not have to be unique, and if two BSTs have the same contents, then summing the node contents will give you the same results in each case, which satisfies the `hashCode` contract.  Remember -- `return 0` is *always* a valid implementation of `hashCode()`; uniqueness is not required.

(Summing the hashCodes of the node contents is, in fact, how `TreeSet.hashCode()` is implemented.)

On the other hand, if you care about structure, you could do something simple like implementing `Node.hashCode()` with

```
int h = contents.hashCode();
h = h * 31 + Objects.hashCode(leftChild);
h = h * 31 + Objects.hashCode(rightChild);
return h;
```

...and that'd get you a decent structure-respecting hash function, too.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I realize the structure matters tremendously in my case. But thanks for the `TreeSet.hashCode()`: +1.

Comment: Added an implementation for that case.

Comment: How do I implement the equals method in this case?

Comment: The same way you'd do for any other Object?  Check the contents are equal, check the left children are equal, check the right children are equal.