# Implementing equals and hashcode for a BST

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

This question is sort of a follow up to [Implementing hashCode for a BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949683/implementing-hashcode-for-a-bst). My question was poorly thought through and so I got an answer that I am not sure how to use.

I need to implement `equals` for a BST: so that **iff** two BSTs are equal in structure and content, then `equals` returns true. As such, I imagine I also need to implement the `hashCode` function. I got the answer for the hashCode function such that the trees are equal in structure and content.

```
@Override
puclic int hashCode(){
  int h = Objects.hashCode(data);//data is int
  int child=0;
  if(null != left)
    child =left.hashCode();
  if(null != right)
    child+= right.hashCode();
  if(0<child) h= h*31+child;
  return h;
}
```

But then how do I implement the equals function? Will the following work **iff** the trees are equal in both structure and content?

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Node otherRoot){
   return root.hashCode() == otherRoot.hashCode();
}
```

Might there be circumstances where I can false positives?

Or should my hashCode be

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
  int h = contents.hashCode();
  h = h * 31 + Objects.hashCode(leftChild);
  h = h * 31 + Objects.hashCode(rightChild);
  return h;
}
```

and in this latter case, would my `equals` avoid false positives?

Comment: Two hashcodes being the same doesn't mean two Objects are equal.  The rule should be "two Objects that are considered equal should have the same hashcode".  Multiplying by 31 doesn't do anything useful; you'll probably cause an arithmetic overflow for big enough tree or large enough int values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the following work **iff** the trees are equal in both structure and content? `root.hashCode() == otherRoot.hashCode()`

No, it would not work, because hash code equality is a one-way street: when objects are equal, hash codes must be equal. However, when objects are not equal, hash codes may or may not be equal. This makes sense once you apply a [*pigeonhole principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle): the number of possible hash codes is about 4B, while the number of possible BSTs is virtually infinite.

You can build a comparison in the same way that you built the hash code - i.e. recursively:

- Check if the values at the nodes being compared are equal to each other. If the values are different, return `false`
- Check if both nodes have a left subtree. If one of them has a left subtree and the other one does not, return `false`
- Check if both nodes have a right subtree. If one of them has a right subtree and the other one does not, return `false`
- Apply `equals` recursively to left subtrees. If the result is `false`, return `false`
- Apply `equals` recursively to right subtrees. If the result is `false`, return `false`
- Return `true`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Objects is, but your last hashCode() example needs to handle null, I would think something like:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  int h = contents.hashCode();
  if (leftChild != null) h = h* 31 + leftChild.hashCode();
  if (rightChild != null) h = h * 31 + rightChild.hashCode();
  return h;
}
```

I can see overflowing h if the tree is deep enough, with all the h * 31.

The [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) for hashCode does not guarantee equality, so you probably need to call equals all the way down the tree to make sure everything balances out.

Comment: [`Objects.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode-java.lang.Object-) takes care of the nullcheck

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this exactly but here's somewhere to start

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  // exact same object
  if(this === o) {
    return true;
  }

  if(!o instanceof Node) {
    return false
  }

  Node otherTree = (Node) o;

  boolean selfHasLeft = this.left == null,
          selfHasRight = this.right == null,
          otherHasLeft = otherTree.left == null,
          otherHasRight = otherTree.right == null;

  // this tree must have the same children as the other tree
  if(selfHasLeft != otherHasLeft || selfHasRight != otherHasRight) {
    return false;
  }

  // must have same value
  if(this.value != other.value) {
    return false;
  }

  // if they have no children then now they should be the same tree
  // otherwise, check that their children are the same
  if(!selfHasLeft && !selfHasRight) {
    return true;
  } else if(selfHasLeft && !selfHasRight) {
    return this.left.equals(otherTree.left);
  } else if(selfHasRight && !selfHasLeft) {
    return this.right.equals(otherTree.right);
  } else {
    return this.left.equals(otherTree.left) && this.right.equals(otherTree.right);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second `hashCode` implementation looks good to me, but you can never avoid hashcode collisions when the number of possible objects are greater than the range of an `int` - which is the case here so you should not use the hashcode in `equals`.

What you should do is something like this (assuming the class name is `BST`):

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if(this == other) {
        return true;
    }
    if(!(other instanceof BST)) {
        // If other is null we will end up here
        return false;
    }

    BST bst = (BST) other;

    // Check equality of the left child
    if(left != null) {
        if(!left.equals(other.left)) {
            // Left childs aren't equal
            return false;
        }
    } else if (other.left != null) {
        // this.left is null but other.left isn't
        return false;
    }

    // Check equality of the right child
    if(right != null) {
        if(!right.equals(other.right)) {
            // Right childs aren't equal
            return false;
        }
    } else if (other.right != null) {
        // this.right is null but other.right isn't
        return false;
    }
    // Both left and right childs are equal
    return true;
}
```